# How To Tell If amiibo Is First-Run Or Reprint

Tags: amiibo

How does one tell the difference between figures made during the first-run of a specific amiibo figure and a reprint of it? Are the tells character-specific or consistent across all figures? Also, I'm looking for differences both on the figures themselves and the card (packaging) and photo proof would be great.

Comment: Some of them have different details (i.e. Marth's boots), some of them not. They should have a different code on the manual (ending with C0, C1...) or a different serial number imprinted on the back, which usually indicates the release week (W1, W2...). The front card is always the same for every print.

Comment: @pinckerman Thanks. I looked that up and found this [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/amiibo/comments/2q1s0k/research_on_amiibo_manufacturing_dates/) all about decoding the serial numbers on the back, in case anyone else is interested.

Comment: @RedEagle2000 If you'd like, you can self-answer your question using information from the linked reddit post